# How can I get from this query, the first two digits of the column "Version"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the first two digits of the column Version, I have tried different ways to do it but none is valid, I have tried with LEN and SUBSTRING but there is no way, I don't know if you can help me.

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') as SP_installed, 
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as Version;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is for MySQL? Looks like SQL Server to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cast as a varchar then use `left` to return the first two digits.

```
select
ServerProperty('ProductLevel') as SP_installed, 
ServerProperty('ProductVersion') as Version,
Left(Cast(ServerProperty('ProductVersion')as varchar(20)), 2);
```

Note as you want the leftmost digits you can in fact just achieve that with `cast` only

```
select
ServerProperty('ProductLevel') as SP_installed, 
ServerProperty('ProductVersion') as Version,
Cast(ServerProperty('ProductVersion')as varchar(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the value as a `VARCHAR` and then `SUBSTRING()` will do it.

For example:

```
SELECT
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') as SP_installed, 
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') as Version,
  substring(cast(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')as varchar(100)), 1, 2);
```

Result:

```
SP_installed  Version       (No column name)
------------  ------------  ----------------
RTM           15.0.4053.23  15
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0830447d4cc93a1605e78b57dcf37c48).